# Would removing a SIM disable the phone number and block text scams

Tags: sms, scam, simcard

I have a PAYG basic Nokia mobile, not a smartphone, and have noticed on my EE A/c there is a transaction for a Text Service with a charge of 15p, appearing every so often, which is nothing to do with me.  I'm in my 70's and wouldn't even know how to set up a Text Service.  I have reported it to EE and they have confirmed it as a scam and are looking into it. They also told me to report it as SPAM to 7726 which I've done, and they answered asking for the spammer's number which I gave them.  Hopefully they can sort this out.  Also, I have to get in touch with EE if this charge continues to pop up on my account.

In the meantime, as I don't use my mobile that much, I was wondering if I removed the sim card which is service locked to EE, would this disable my number being used and stop the scammer from charging my A/c for the Text Service?  Please note, I don't actually receive any phone messages from the scammer, just this charge being allocated to my A/c.  Any helpful replies would be most welcome!

Comment: What does EE and A/c stand for in this case?

Comment: I'm from the UK so apologise for my 'Englishness'!  EE is a phone service provider in the UK and the lovely Kevin Bacon does all the EE ads. on the telly.  A/c is just an abbreviation for 'Account'.  Yes, I'm laughing now - we English are a quaint lot !

Comment: Hi Joanie, have you read https://ee.co.uk/help/help-new/billing-usage-and-top-up/understanding-my-bill/why-is-my-bill-higher-than-normal and https://ee.co.uk/help/help-new/billing-usage-and-top-up/understanding-my-bill/third-party-services ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you accidentally subscribed to some service for 15 pences?.. That's a rather small sum, so I find it rather weird.

Comment: Sir Muffington - No, I definitely did not.  I only use my mobile (cell phone) for phone calls and texts, and taking my age into account, they are few and far between!  Hence, I don't have a smartphone - no need for one, my laptop suits me fine.  Anyway, EE confirmed that it is a scam.  I'm hoping that the Spam alert I sent to the 'Spam People' as I call them, will sort it out.  I keep a close eye on my Account, and guess what, another charge popped up just a couple of hrs. before I messaged Spam People.  In fact I may have to change my number.  The outcome will be revealed - watch this space!!

Comment: Hi Bruno, thank you for suggestions, which I have read on EE and none of which applies to me.  I have a plan with EE which only costs £1 for 7 days (£4 a month) with more than enough texts and minutes I could ever use.  I don't have any extras or add-ons except for the scumbag who keeps charging my A/c for the Text Service.  I must sound pretty boring I know, but hey, when you get to my age I'm just grateful I'm still here!